# How to check if embedded-jetty in Spring-boot has HTTPRequests to Process?

Tags: spring-boot, embedded-jetty

I am designing a webservice that runs on embedded-jetty in Spring-Boot. I have a strict requirement on the memory usage of the Java Process. The service should process the incoming requests sequentially. It has been desired when there are no incoming requests to the server, the server should close the application context and exits the java process. At the end memory is freed when the process is exited.

I have tried closing the application context but it only closes/cleans the contexts but it doesn't close the process itself.

```
private ApplicationContext context;

@PostMapping("/shutdown")
public void shutdownContext() {
    ((ConfigurableApplicationContext) context).close();
}

@Override
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ctx) throws BeansException {
    this.context = ctx;
}
```

I expect that there is a neat and clean way first to close the context and later check if embedded-jetty has requests in some internal cache. I expect first to check if Jetty has requests in cache and once they are processed and there are no incoming requests then we can first end the context and later exit the process.

Comment: The spring boot actuator already has a shutdown endpoint to gracefully shutdown an application.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html

I would try it and test that all requests are cleared before it exits.

Comment: Jetty has a request queue, not cache. That queue will be empty, unless you are processing thousands of requests per second.  If you are processing thousands of requests per second then you don't have strict memory usage requirements.

Comment: @darren: yeah my biggest problem is „How to find out if there are any unprocessed request left before shutdown endpoint is called?“

Comment: @joakim : the Memory usages also depends on the kind of processing is done inside a httprequest. I am not considering in particular the memory usage due to jetty. My ultimate goal is to kill the Java process neatly when all requests are processed.

Comment: I would do what @DarrenForsythe points out, as both spring-boot and Jetty have graceful shutdown mechanics that will wait for in-process http exchanges to complete before shutting down (with timeouts).  Note: This is based on active exchanges, not queued requests, not open connections.  Standard HTTP rules apply.